# python - Converting python dictionary values to respective key-value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary

Currently I am working with Django querysets and am getting a result like this:

```
[{'week': 29, 'avg': 137.6}, {'week': 30, 'avg': 138.6}, {'week': 31, 'avg': 138.06666666666666}]
```

As you can see, its a list of dictionaries.

I want to deal with simply:

```
{29: 137.6, 30: 138.6, 31: 138.066}
```

I'm having some trouble looping my head through all this. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply use *dictionary comprehension*:

```
{ d['week'] : d['avg'] for d in data }
```

Where `data` is your list of dictionaries. This produces:

```
>>> { d['week'] : d['avg'] for d in data }
{29: 137.6, 30: 138.6, 31: 138.06666666666666}
```

The dictionary comprehension will thus iterate through `data`, and for every element `d` (a dictionary), it will associate `d['week']` (key) with `d['avg']` (value) in the result.

In case it is not a list of dictionaries, but still a queryset, you should - like [@JonClemens says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45470281/python-converting-python-dictionary-values-to-respective-key-value-pairs/45470303?noredirect=1#comment77901762_45470303) - use the following expression:

```
dict(queryset.values_list('week','avg'))
```

Here `values_list('week','avg')` will construct an iterable of 2-tuples that contain the week as first element, and the average as second element. If the `dict(..)` constructor obtains an iterable of 2-tuples, it will construct a dictionary where the first element of every tuple is the key, and the second element of the tuple the associated value.

Comment: OP mentions querysets so they're probably after: `dict(queryset.values_list('week', 'avg'))`...

Comment: @JonClements: thanks. I added this to the answer with a brief explanation :).

Comment: This is fantastic and very simple! Thank you very much.